# Adding date to label in QGIS Atlas composer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, atlas, date

I'm trying to add the current date into a label for use in a composer for colleagues to run on a daily basis. The label is currently;

```
Bins to be delivered: [% "Count" %]
```

All I need to add is the current date, but when I make the label this;

```
Bins to be delivered: [% "Count" %] as at $now()
```

nothing happens.

Do I need to enter something in the 2 end brackets to bring the date in? Or is it something else I need to do?

Answer (score 9):

Just tried it out, for me (QGis 2.18) `format_date(now(),'dd.MM.yyyy')` works.

/edit: You need to put the [% %] around your whole expression, then it should work, like: `[%'Datum: ' || format_date(now(),'dd.MM.yyyy')%]`

Note the pipes (||) between the parts of the expression, they are necessary.

/edit2: `now()` gives you the full date, incl. time, which is a bit much, isn't it?